# How to get total lines count of certain extensions after a specific commit of git

Tags: git

For example, I'd like to count lines of all files with extensions `.c`, `.cpp` and `.h` after a specific git commit, how to achieve that?

`git ls-files | grep -E "\.(c|cpp|h)$" | xargs wc -l` is working for current version. How to get it used for previous specific version?

Answer (score 0):

Here are my ideas...

---

## Stat way

git diff --numstat HEAD sha_here -- '*.c' '*.cpp'

---

## Grep way

git diff --unified=0 --no-prefix HEAD e3394319f0efedf990693efaf853fa4e11fe4d0d -- **/*.config | grep for '+' and '-'

Comment: It seems only list the files that changed, and I'd like to get all files, whether changed or not.